# how to loop through column names in R

Tags: r

```
genres=c("Action","Adventure","Animation","Biography","Comedy","Crime",
 "Documentary","Drama","Family","Game.Show","Horror","Music","Musical",
 "Mystery","Romance","Sci.Fi","Short","Thriller","War","Western")
```

This is my vector of genres.

Another data set has the same column names.

This is the data set column names

```
"Title"        "Genre"        "imdbRating"   "Release_Year" 
"Action"       "Adventure"    "Animation"    "Biography"    "Comedy"    
"Crime"        "Documentary"  "Drama"        "Family" 
"Fantasy"      "Game.Show"    "Horror"       "Music"
"Musical"      "Mystery"      "N.A"          "Romance"
"Sci.Fi"       "Short"        "Sport"        "Thriller"   
"War"          "Western"
```

I want to run this command for all genres replacing each genre with the value.

```
     data_predict$genres[grepl("*genres*", data_predict$Genre)]=1

Orignal Data set


        data_predict<-structure(list(Genre = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi", 
"Action, Drama, War", "Sci-Fi"), class = "factor"), Action = c(0, 
0, 0), Adventure = c(0, 0, 0), Animation = c(0, 0, 0), Biography = c(0, 
0, 0), Comedy = c(0, 0, 0), Crime = c(0, 0, 0), Documentary = c(0, 
0, 0), Drama = c(0, 0, 0), Family = c(0, 0, 0), Game.Show = c(0, 
0, 0), Horror = c(0, 0, 0), Music = c(0, 0, 0), Musical = c(0, 
0, 0), Mystery = c(0, 0, 0), Romance = c(0, 0, 0), Sci.Fi = c(0, 
0, 0), Short = c(0, 0, 0), Thriller = c(0, 0, 0), War = c(0, 
0, 0), Western = c(0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Genre", "Action", "Adventure", 
"Animation", "Biography", "Comedy", "Crime", "Documentary", "Drama", 
"Family", "Game.Show", "Horror", "Music", "Musical", "Mystery", 
"Romance", "Sci.Fi", "Short", "Thriller", "War", "Western"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected result

```
data_predicted<-structure(list(Genre = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi", 
    "Action, Drama, War", "Sci-Fi"), class = "factor"), Action = c(0, 
    1, 1), Adventure = c(0, 1, 0), Animation = c(0, 0, 0), Biography = c(0, 
    0, 0), Comedy = c(0, 0, 0), Crime = c(0, 0, 0), Documentary = c(0, 
    0, 0), Drama = c(0, 0, 1), Family = c(0, 0, 0), Game.Show = c(0, 
    0, 0), Horror = c(0, 0, 0), Music = c(0, 0, 0), Musical = c(0, 
    0, 0), Mystery = c(0, 0, 0), Romance = c(0, 0, 0), Sci.Fi = c(0, 
    0, 0), Short = c(0, 0, 0), Thriller = c(0, 0, 0), War = c(0, 
    0, 1), Western = c(0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Genre", "Action", "Adventure", 
    "Animation", "Biography", "Comedy", "Crime", "Documentary", "Drama", 
    "Family", "Game.Show", "Horror", "Music", "Musical", "Mystery", 
    "Romance", "Sci.Fi", "Short", "Thriller", "War", "Western"), row.names = c(NA, 
    3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: the genres are "Sci-fi" " Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi" "Action, Drama, War"            I want to update those colums which contains the genreeg.like a row contains action drama and war so its Action Drama and War should become 1

Comment: i am using this code `data_predict$Action[grepl("Action", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Adventure[grepl("*Adventure*", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Animation[grepl("*Animation*", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Biography[grepl("*Biography*", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Comedy[grepl("*Comedy*", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Crime[grepl("*Crime*", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Documentary[grepl("*Documentary*", data_predict$Genre)]=1
data_predict$Drama[grepl("*Drama*", data_predict$Genre)]=1` I want to reduce the steps.Can u help me with this

Comment: A u can see in the dataset i want to update only those columns which contain the  genre.Eg. the second row contains Action,Adventure and Sci-fi so Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi should be set 1 for this row.[link](http://s15.postimg.org/wumvwxtor/ask.png)

Comment: paste(genres, collapse="|") didnt work

Comment: A image is not helpful as I had to manually type in the data to test.  Please check the guidelines [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is saying that i have exceeded the characters.I used dput but it gave me a very long structure for just first 3 rows.

Comment: Looks like you have to loop, here, i.e `lapply(names(data_predict), function(x) {x1 <- data_predict[,x]; x1[grepl(paste(".*?,x.*"), data_predict$Genre] <- 1; x1})` (not tested)

Comment: Then try with `dput(droplevels(yourdata[1:5,1:4]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(data_predict$Genre), ', '))
```

Or

```
 data_predict[-1] <- lapply(names(data_predict)[-1],
      function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, data_predict$Genre)))
```

Comment: I am new so sorry for the trouble caused.Thanks alot